# Docker Compose - Redis container refusing connection to Node container

Tags: node.js, docker, redis, docker-compose

No matter what I try I can't seem to get my node app to connect to redis between containers within the same docker-compose yml config.  I've seen a lot of similar questions but *none* of the answers seem to work.

I'm using official images in both cases, not building my own

I am putting "redis" as my host and setting it as hostname in my docker compose YML config

```
const client = redis.createClient({ host: "redis" });
```

in my `redis.conf` I am using `bind 0.0.0.0`

This what the console is printing out:

```
 Redis connection to redis:6379 failed - getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND redis redis:6379

 Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:6379
at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1107:14)
  errno: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  syscall: 'connect',
  address: '127.0.0.1',
port: 6379 
}
```

This is my docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'
services:
  server:
    image: "node:10-alpine"
    working_dir: /usr/src/app
    user: "node"
    command: "npm start"
    volumes:
      - .:/usr/src/app
    ports:
      - '3000:3000'
      - '3001:3001'
      - '9229:9229' # Node debugging port
    environment:
      - IS_DOCKER=1
      - NODE_ENV=DEVELOPMENT
    depends_on:
      - db

  db:
    image: "redis:5.0-alpine"
    expose:
      - '6379'
    volumes:
      - ./redis.conf:/usr/local/etc/redis/redis.conf
      - redis-data:/data
    command:
      - redis-server
      - /usr/local/etc/redis/redis.conf
    hostname: redis

volumes:
  redis-data:
```

**UPDATE**

Here's my `redis.conf`, it's not much.

```
bind 0.0.0.0
appendonly yes
appendfilename "my_app.aof"
appendfsync always
```

**UPDATE 2**

Things I've noticed and tried

- in my original setup, when I run `docker inspect` I can see they are both joined to the same network. when I `exec`...`/bin/bash` into the redis container I  can successfully ping the server container but when I'm in the server container it can not ping the redis one.
- `network_mode: bridge` -adding that to both containers does not work

I did get one baby step closer by trying out this:

```
server:
   network_mode: host
redis:
   network_mode: service:host
```

I'm on a Mac and in order to get host mode to work you need to do that.  It does work in the sense that my server successfully connects to the redis container.  However, hitting `localhost:3000` does not work even though I'm forwarding the ports

Comment: I thought I figured it out for a moment using `network_mode: host` but a new problem happend where I could not reach `localhost:3000` in my browser.  I did see  the app run and connect to redis successfully though

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```yaml
version: '3'
services:
  server:
    image: "node:10-alpine"
    #network_mode: bridge
    #links is necessary if you use network_mode: bridge
    #links: [redis]
    networks:
      - default
    working_dir: /usr/src/app
    user: "node"
    command: "npm start"
    volumes:
      - .:/usr/src/app
    ports:
      - '3000:3000'
      - '3001:3001'
      - '9229:9229' # Node debugging port
    environment:
      - IS_DOCKER=1
      - NODE_ENV=DEVELOPMENT
    depends_on:
      - redis

  redis:
    image: "redis:5.0-alpine"
    #container_name: redis
    #network_mode: bridge
    networks:
      - default
    expose:
      - '6379'
    volumes:
      - ./redis.conf:/usr/local/etc/redis/redis.conf
      - redis-data:/data
    command:
      - redis-server
      - /usr/local/etc/redis/redis.conf

volumes:
  redis-data:

networks:
  default:
```

Rename the container to the hostname you want to use: **redis** in your case instead of *db*. 
To make it accessible over the docker network you will have to put them on the same network like above or use `network_mode: bridge` and `links: [redis]` instead.

Try this to test your network:
`docker ps` to get the current container id or running name from the server container
`docker exec -it id/name /bin/sh`
Now you have a shell inside *server* and should be able to resolve *redis* via:
`ping redis` or `nc -zv redis 6379`

Comment: no luck.  I've tried with and without the container_name as redis, also removing the hostname redis as well.  I've tried not using my custom conf as well.  nothing seems to work

Comment: You do not need `container_name:` or explicit `links:` for this to work.  (The `hostname:` declaration is also ineffective.)  The important change from the original `docker-compose.yml` file is renaming `db` to `redis`, to match the expected host name.

Comment: What @DavidMaze says is correct, but sometimes docker-compose can be tricky. Please check my updated answer to debug your issue

Comment: bridge mode doesn't work however (in default  network mode) when I shell into the server container and `ping redis` I get this `PING redis (172.18.0.2): 56 data bytes; ping: permission denied (are you root?)` which is promising!  `redis` is being mapped to the right IP! but it's just being denied by the redis container for some reason (or maybe the server container is blocking it?)

Comment: I believe this might have to do with using alpine.  When I switched to the `node:10` image I can successfully `ping redis` from  within the node server container.  But for some reason I still can't connect to it in the node app

Comment: I just rann it myself and it works fine. try `nc -zv redis 6379` from the npm container shell. It should tell you: `redis (ip:6379) open`. So you can start setting up everything the way you want to or do you have any more problems? Ping won't work because you are running it as user: node

Comment: @Francisc0 It looks like you moved on with the project. It would be nice if you accept my answer. It worked fine for me. If you have any more questions, feel free to ask

Answer (score 0):

For those who still getting this error
i found that in new versions of redis - 4 and up
you need to configure the client like this:

```
const client = createClient({
  socket: {
    host: host,
     port: process.env.REDIS_PORT,
   },
});
```

it solved my problem

then in docker compose file you don't need to specify ports

```js
version: "3.4"
services:
  redis-server:
    image: "redis:latest"
    restart: always
  api:
    depends_on:
      - redis-server
    restart: always
    build: .
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
```